# Illumination properties of black lights

Tags: photonics

An elderly friend of mind whose eyesight is fading  recently asked me if there was a way to illuminate her new induction stove top so that the "burner rings" would be easier to see, to her it just looks like a big black non descript surface. I was thinking maybe a blacklight would illuminate the little square marks embedded in the glass that define the pan rings or locations. I suppose I could just buy one and try it but to save time and money I thought I would ask the experts here to see if anyone had any experience with black light being used to make these kinds of markings pop out visually.

Comment: What was the lighting used in the shop - surely she could see the markings then? Or, someone else just “bought one that fitted”...

Comment: @ Solar Mike:  Yes, the latter.

Comment: Are you one person with two accounts?

Comment: i'm doubtful it will work, but if you want to try be sure to get fluorescent or led black lights (or try both as the spectrum is going to be different.)

Comment: also consider if there might be some suitable high temp paint you could use to enhance the markings. (actually i suppose an induction top doesn't even get all that hot if you put some marks a little outside where the pan sits.)

Comment: @SolarMike: I actually have 7 different accounts !   :-)   I started using different identities when I realized that the government was monitoring and censoring all my emails. I do it to keep them amused. Everything on the internet is monitored by the NSA , even the so called "Dark Web" where fools think they can navigate the web anonymously .